# json crud operations using core javascript

Tags: javascript, json, crud, using, operations

I want to perform the following CRUD operations on this json
        1)Update content_available as true for code  (EN, CN).
        this is what i have tried. but it doesnt work.

myObj = {
        "data": [{
            "code": "EN",
            "language": "English",
            "content_available": true,
            "isdefault": true
        }, {
            "code": "AR",
            "language": "Arabic",
            "content_available": true,
            "isdefault": false,
                    "default" : true

```
    }, {
        "code": "BR",
        "language": "Brazilian Portuguese",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false
    }, {
        "code": "CN",
        "language": "Simplified Chinese",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false,
                "default" : true
    }, {
        "code": "TW",
        "language": "Traditional Chinese",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false
    }, {
        "code": "DE",
        "language": "German",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false
    }, {
        "code": "ES",
        "language": "Spanish",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false
    }, {
        "code": "FR",
        "language": "French",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false
    }, {
        "code": "JP",
        "language": "Japanese",
        "content_available": true,
        "isdefault": false,
                 "default" : true
    }, {
        "code": "RU",
        "language": "Russian",
        "content_available": false,
        "isdefault": false
    }],
    "success": true
    }

 function setContentAvailable() {
     for (var key in myObj.data) {
         if (myObj["data"]["code"] === "EN" && myObj[data][code] === "CN") {
             myObj.data.content_available = false;
         }
     }
 }
 setContentAvailable();
 console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code that you already tried, and raise specific question.

Comment: Done.Please have a look at it.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, a `for` loop is used but the `key` is ignored... and the check for `EN` or `CN` should be `||` (or), not `&&` (and).

To **Update content_available as true for code (EN, CN)**, the code should be:

```
 function setContentAvailable() {
   for (var key in myObj.data) {
     if (myObj["data"][key]["code"] === "EN" || myObj["data"][key]["code"] === "CN") {
         myObj["data"][key]["content_available"] = true;
     }
   }
 }
 setContentAvailable();
```

Comment: Hey shaochancs! ? Thanks !! It does work. I didn't know how to use the key in this code. Thanks for teaching me this!

Comment: @SChavan you're welcome. If your problem is solved and this answer is helpful, maybe it can be accepted?

Comment: @shaochancs just accepted your answer. I am sorry I didn't know I had to do that, since I am new to stackoverflow.